# Vertx event bus reconnect

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I would like to use vertx eventbus from Javascript client (mainly smartphones). My problem is when I send the phone to standby, the eventbus disconnects after a couple of seconds and doesn't reconnect after wake up. I try to reconnect in eventbus onclose(), but it doesn't always work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying reconnection only once, why don't you try to reconnect in a loop:

```
eventBus.onclose = function {
 while(state != vertx.EventBus.OPEN) {
   setInterval(function(){
      // Recreate an eventbus object and re-register all callbacks included this one 
      initialiseEventbus()
   },3000);
 }
}
```

The above is not the most elegant solution, but unfortunately there's no (re)connect method to call on vertxbus.js, nor a default automatic reconnection strategy. That's a pity, but I'm sure the dev team would happy to accept a ticket on this.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been added to working version of vert.x, but is not yet official. However, you can import and use `vertx-eventbus.js` :

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/pull/660

After you initialize the EventBus with e.g. `var eb = new EventBus("/eventbus");`, you can enable it with `eb.enableReconnect(true);`